# How can I inline every n objects within a loop in html with flask using jinja

Tags: python, flask

Let us say I have 30 numbers 1-30. If I loop through the list in flask and print out the numbers (

{{ num }}

), It will print out like so:

1

2

3

4

...

What I want to do is to have it print out like this:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

so that 3 elements are on the same line and then it moves to the next line. Is there a way to do this using jinja and inline blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
{% if num % 3 == 0 %}
    {{ num }} <br>
{% else %}
    {{ num }}
{% endif %}
```

Assuming you're using `jinja2` for templates

Comment: It's probably better to use [`loop.index`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) (or `loop.index0`) than relying on the actual value.